# If $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ and $g_n \rightharpoonup g$, and $|f_n|_H - |g_n|_H \to |f|_H-|g|_H$, does $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

We work in a Hilbert space $H$. If $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ and $g_n \rightharpoonup g$, and 
$$|f_n|_H - |g_n|_H \to |f|_H-|g|_H$$
is there any chance that $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$?

Of course this is true when $g_n =g = 0$ but I don't think what I want is going to hold unless I miss something.

Comment: Note that you assertion is true if $|f_n|_H + |g_n|_H \to |f|_H + |g|_H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: $f_n = g_n$ any sequence converging weakly but not strongly.